# How i can read the nested properties and pushing to the array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I want to read the JSON properties. if type is array or object or jsonp then i have to read the nested properties and need push it one array which should also be nested.
like:

```
{
  name:"test",
  type:"array"
   [name]: {
      name: "test1",
       type: "..."
   }
 }
```

JSON object to read:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "value": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "required": [
          "@odata.etag",
          "id",
          "createdDateTime",
          "lastModifiedDateTime",
          "changeKey",
          "originalStartTimeZone",
          "originalEndTimeZone",
          "iCalUId",
          "reminderMinutesBeforeStart",
          "isReminderOn",
          "hasAttachments",
          "subject",
          "bodyPreview",
          "importance",
          "sensitivity",
          "isAllDay",
          "isCancelled",
          "isOrganizer",
          "responseRequested",
          "showAs",
          "type",
          "webLink",
          "isOnlineMeeting",
          "onlineMeetingProvider",
          "allowNewTimeProposals",
          "isDraft",
          "hideAttendees"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "end": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "dateTime",
              "timeZone"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "dateTime": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              },
              "timeZone": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "body": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "contentType",
              "content"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "content": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              },
              "contentType": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "start": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "dateTime",
              "timeZone"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "dateTime": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              },
              "timeZone": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "showAs": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "iCalUId": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "isDraft": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "subject": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "webLink": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "isAllDay": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "displayName",
              "locationType",
              "uniqueIdType",
              "address",
              "coordinates"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "address": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [],
                "properties": {}
              },
              "coordinates": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [],
                "properties": {}
              },
              "displayName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "locationType": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              },
              "uniqueIdType": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "attendees": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "required": [
                "type"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "minLength": 1
                },
                "status": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "required": [
                    "response",
                    "time"
                  ],
                  "properties": {
                    "time": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "minLength": 1
                    },
                    "response": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "minLength": 1
                    }
                  }
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "required": [
                    "name",
                    "address"
                  ],
                  "properties": {
                    "name": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "minLength": 1
                    },
                    "address": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "minLength": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
          },
          "changeKey": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "locations": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "required": [],
              "properties": {}
            }
          },
          "organizer": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "emailAddress"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "emailAddress": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                  "name",
                  "address"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1
                  },
                  "address": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "minLength": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "categories": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "required": [],
              "properties": {}
            }
          },
          "importance": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "recurrence": {},
          "@odata.etag": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "bodyPreview": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "isCancelled": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "isOrganizer": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "sensitivity": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "isReminderOn": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "hideAttendees": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "onlineMeeting": {},
          "transactionId": {},
          "hasAttachments": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "responseStatus": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
              "response",
              "time"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "time": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              },
              "response": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "seriesMasterId": {},
          "createdDateTime": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "isOnlineMeeting": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "onlineMeetingUrl": {},
          "responseRequested": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "originalEndTimeZone": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "lastModifiedDateTime": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "allowNewTimeProposals": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "onlineMeetingProvider": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "originalStartTimeZone": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
          },
          "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        }
      },
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "@odata.context": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "@odata.nextLink": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the "name" property come from?

Comment: name here is test. i have found the solution. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This code will return all the nested values

```
 propertiesObj = "";// the above json
 contextProperties = [];
    generate_properties(propertiesObj, propertiesArray) {
        Object.entries(propertiesObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          //  console.log(value);
          let contextObj = {};
          contextObj["attrName"] = key;
          contextObj["attrId"] = key;
          contextObj["datatype"] = value["type"];
          contextObj["attrType"] = "output";
    
          if (value["type"] == "array" || value["type"] == "object") {
            contextObj[key] = [];
            if (Object.keys(value).includes("items")) {
              this.generate_properties(
                value["items"]["properties"],
                contextObj[key]
              );
            } else {
              this.generate_properties(value["properties"], contextObj[key]);
            }
    
            propertiesArray.push(contextObj);
          } else {
            propertiesArray.push(contextObj);
          }
        });
      }
```